# How to start a data collector upon high CPU load condition?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, automation, diagnostic

I have a Windows 2008R2 server that experience high CPU load for several minutes about once every couple of weeks.

Unfortunately, when these events occurs, logging into the system through RDP or at the console takes so long that, when it's done, the problem is usually gone.

So, I've prepared a perfmon data collector that will capture the relevant data (CPU time per process, details of IIS worker processes, etc.) but I have no idea how to trigger it automatically under high-CPU load condition (as defined in Nagios: that's >99% CPU usage for more than 300 seconds).

Unfortunately, the low frequency of these events makes it difficult to let the data collector run on its own.

I have currently worked around it by using circular logging and leaving it running but that's not really a satisfactory solution.

So, is there a (simple) way to get that data collector started under these conditions ?

Comment: Did you ever get this to work? (Also: Do you know of a way to do this in 2012R2?)

Comment: Not exactly. I planned on starting the data collector using the Nagios script on the system but, in the end, we just left a TS console open with process explorer running and, when Nagios sent us the high-CPU alter, we connected and found the problematic service.

Comment: Okay, thanks, I've now managed to POC this sucessfully on my Win10 laptop. I used a "Performance Counter Alert" to trigger a Performance counter data collection. Steps from this answer: SF, 2015-07-05, [*Performance counter alert not working*](https://serverfault.com/questions/703608/performance-counter-alert-not-working/703920)