# Performance counter alert not working

Tags: windows-server-2008, performance-monitoring

I want to monitor for example CPU usage on a server and run a script which will figure out the most demanding processes and logs it into file.
I planned to use Performance counter alert which can be defined in Perfmon / Data collector sets / User Defined. But somehow it does not seem to do anything. I set "alert action" to log an entry in application event log and alert task to run my script but none of this happens when the conditions are met...
[image]

You can clearly see that exactly this value much exceeds the set threshold but still no alert is triggered.
[image]

If somebody knows how to set it up, please let me know.

Comment: seems like neither Processor nor Processor Information objects work.

Comment: Logical disk \ % free space also no reaction to changing value

Answer (score 3):

So after a lot more googling (I hoped somebody here will do it for me ;) I figured it out!

## Task field

The `Run this task when an alert is triggered:` field is not a path to a program, but name of a task which needs to be defined in `Task Scheduler`! I would expect this field to be a combobox with selection of all tasks, but it is not, so it is pretty unclear what it means. So I defined a simple task in Task scheduler (`taskschd.msc`) with action `"start a program"` and now it works!

## Not "Application" log

Also about the event log entry: The `Log an entry in the application event log` check box is somewhat misnamed. [It indeed logs, but hides it deep into `Applications and Services Logs\Microsoft\Windows\Diagnosis-PLA\Operational`](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/977edcef-00ab-47ad-8b74-d64a113cc04f/performance-monitor-alerts-not-triggering-events?forum=winservergen). I was looking for a message in `Application` event log as the settings window says.

## Further reading

- Taylor Brown, Microsoft, 2012-09-25, [*Leveraging Event Log Messages and Performance Counter Alerts To Automate Hyper-V*](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/taylorb/archive/2012/09/25/leveraging-event-log-messages-to-automatically-move-vm-s.aspx) (Archived [here](https://archive.is/IYITd).)